# Should I say Abelian monoïd or commutative monoïd

Tags: group-theory, terminology, abelian-groups, monoid

I usually say, "Abelian group" rather than "commutative group", not sure if that's because I studied in the United states during the 1980s.    But it seems people in Europe say, "commutative monoïd".   I'm preparing a lecture for my computer science students where I talk about the definitions and simple examples of groups, monoïds, rings, and semirings.

The lecture covers just enough ($+\varepsilon$) to implement shortest path algorithms and generalized exponentiation.  I.e., calculate $x^n$ in a monoïd, recursively by $x^n = x^{n-1} \times x$ if $n$ is odd and $x^n = (x\times x)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ if $n$ is even. And using that exponentiation step to efficiently compute matrix powers where matrix components come from tropical: semiring $(Z,min,\infty,+,0)$.

It feels strange that I always say "Abelian group", yet "commutative monoïd".

Any advice?

Comment: Even more confusingly, "abelian ring" is used to mean something different from "commutative ring"! For monoids, I don't think either "abelian" or "commutative" would seem weird or unusual. (Although calling them "monoïds" rather than "monoids" does seem weird to me: the French word is "monoïde" but I think that's because they pronounce the "o" and "i" as separate vowel sounds, which we don't in English.)

Comment: I personally prefer to call them commutative monoids, but both is actually fine.

Comment: BTW, you should capitalize Abelian in my opinion, similar to capitalizing Boolean.

Comment: The capitalization is a matter of style. Many authors don't capitalize terms that are derived from people's names if they are mathematical. Hartshorne writes "noetherian."

Comment: I teach my French students that they have to capitalize these words in English even though they are not capitalized in French.  I didn't realize this rule had become relaxed.  It's a shame, but you can't prevent the language from changing.  BTW is the rule only for adjectives, or also nouns?  "hilbert space" vs "Hilbert space" ?

Comment: In French, the rule is simple: surname takes capital *(espace de Hilbert, surface de Riemann)* but the derived adjective doesn't *(espace hilbertien, variété riemannienne)*. In English, the standard rule is to always capitalize (Riemann, Riemannian), but for the older adjectives (abelian, noetherian), there's a tendency to omit the capital. It might have be influenced by French (which was more influential some time ago) but I'm not sure.

Comment: You write "monoïde" in French (oï means you have to pronounce o and i, instead of "oi", which in French is usually pronounced "wah"), but in English it's just written "monoid" (and "groupoid", etc). (A contrario in French one writes "coordonnée" while in English it's sometimes (rarely) "coördinate" to emphasize that the two "o" are separated, while in French "oo" has no individual meaning.)

Comment: "Abelian" is more used in group theory, while "commutative" is more used in ring theory. If you want compute matrix powers and the components come from a (semi-)ring, then I would use "commutative".

Answer (score 3):

I guess "commutative" is just better. "Abelian" is widely used for groups but that should be viewed as part of an established harmless tradition, and nobody blames if you say "commutative group", except maybe your vocal cords in case of a sore throat. In the same fashion group theory comes with some obsolete terminology, such as saying "order" in lieu of "cardinal", due to the initial definition of group as permutation groups on a set, before abstract groups were introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Although the term *Abelian semigroup* is used by some people, it looks like most books on semigroups use the term *commutative semigroup*.

This includes Clifford and Preston's classical treatise *The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups*, Howie's book *Fundamentals of semigroup theory*, Okninski's *Semigroups of Matrices*, my own book *Varieties of formal languages*, Higgins's *Techniques of semigroup theory*, Rhodes and Steinberg's *The $q$-theory of finite semigroups*, Lawson's *Inverse semigroups, the theory of partial symmetries*, Steinberg's more recent book  *Representation theory of finite monoids*,  and of course Redei's *Theory of finitely generated commutative semigroups* and Grillet's reference book *Commutative semigroups*.

In conclusion, I think it is safe to stick on the term *commutative semigroup*.